# Generate Google Cloud Console query URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Does anyone know how to generate a Google Cloud Console query URL to search for instances such as:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?project=myProject&instancesquery=%255B%257B_22k_22_3A_22_22_2C_22t_22_3A10_2C_22v_22_3A_22_5C_22**myInstanceName**_5C_22_22%257D%255D&instancessize=50
```